# What is the formal definition of 'string'?

Tags: terminology, definition, formal-languages

I just found out about uncountable and infinitary languages and I'm not sure what "string" means now. Originally, I had conceived of a string being, at most, a countable sequence of symbols with a least (leftmost) member. Since this fails to account for several types of infinite-length string (for example, strings that have no first or last symbol, uncountable strings), I'm at a loss as to what "string" means in the first place.

At the very least a string consists of a set [or class?] of symbols$^0$ with *some* kind of order, but I'm not sure where the line between "string" and "digraph" is drawn. If there are no restrictions, then the notion of "string" seems sufficiently general to be indistinguishable from "binary relation."

**Edit:**

To give something of a starting point, I had originally thought to define a general "closure" operation that gives the set of all strings up to a certain (possibly infinite) length.

Let $\gamma$ be some fixed ordinal, then...

$$Cl_\gamma(X)=\bigcup_{i<\gamma}X^i$$

This readily generates the set of $\omega$-length strings when $\gamma=\omega+1$. However, the closure described above excludes strings which are not "well ordered." For example, strings with no leftmost symbol, which can be generated by infintary left-recursive grammars. Even extending the above to count reverse-order types for each ordinal$^1$ excludes the case of "cyclic" and "dense" strings (provided that such things are permitted).

---

$^0$ when referring to the characters of a string as a set [class?], assume that each character is identified with a pair $(k,s)$, where $s$ is the symbol and $k$ is a "tag" distinguishing different instances of $s$. If you take this one step further, then a string is a function from some set [class?] $X$ to a set $S$ of primitive symbols, plus a binary relation [order?] on $X$.

$^1$ $X^{\omega^*}$, appropriately defined, would account for $\omega$-length "left-recursive" strings

Comment: I imagine there are many definitions of string depending on context.

Comment: @copper.hat The context is formal languages over arbitrary (possibly infinite) sets of primitive symbols.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(formal_languages)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee $\Sigma^\omega$ only covers the cases of countable strings with least (leftmost) member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use the term *word* instead of *string*.
Successive notions of words over an alphabet $A$ have been defined and studied: *finite words*, *infinite words*, *bi-infinite words*, *words over ordinals* and *words over linear orderings*. See [1] for a survey.
Cyclic words were also considered: they are equivalence classes of cyclic permutations of finite words.

[1] Véronique Bruyère and Olivier Carton, [Automata on linear orderings](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000006001322), *J. Comput. System Sci.* **73** (2007), no. 1, 1--24. (See also [here](https://www.irif.fr/~carton/Publications/Linear/Kleene/Scattered/jcss.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I noticed that the authors only mention countable words. Is it generally accepted that the length of a word must be countable?

Comment: No, words over any linear order also have been studied, see A. Bès, and O. Carton, A Kleene theorem for languages of words indexed by linear orderings. *Internat. J. Found. Comput. Sci.* **17** (2006), no. 3, 519--541.

Answer (score -1):

$\require{enclose}$ $\require{cancel}$

The following mathematical definitions are consistent with how some mathematicians use strings today.

As an opening example, we can write the string $“\mathtt{normal distribution}”$ in many different ways.

The following is a poor approximation of  `normal distribution` in German (Deutsch):

```
Normalverteilung
```

---

## The Unicode Character Set $\, \mathbb{U}$

Although we wanted a definition for string, we must first define an alphabet or co-domain. This might seem like computer programming, but please bare with me.

> We define $\mathbb{U}$ to be the set of all [Unicode v 15.0 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

We have $149186 = \begin{vmatrix}\mathbb{U}\end{vmatrix}$ or there are $149,186$ characters.

$94$ of the Unicode characters known as the ASCII printable set are shown below:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123
456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFG
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
]^_`abcdefghijklmnop
qrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

---

## Formal Definitions of *Unicode String*

---

**Fuzzy North American Representation of the Definition of Unicode String**

> A **string** is function whose inputs are numbers and the outputs are Unicode characters such that indexing begins at $1$, and we have wrap-around indexing.

**Detailed North American Representation of the Definition of Unicode String**

> For any mapping $\sigma$ from the zalen integers $\mathbb{Z}$ without zero to the set of all Unicode character $\mathbb{U}$ we say that $\sigma$ is a ***string***
>
> > if and only if
>
> There exists $n$ element of the zalen without zero such that:
>
> > if
> >
> > > the absolute value of $n$ is less than or equal to the absolute value of $m$
> > > then
> > > for any $k$ element of the set of all zalen without zero,
> > >
> > > > all of the following:
> > > >
> > > > > if
> > > > >
> > > > > > $-|n|$ is less than or equal to $k$
> > > > > > and
> > > > > > $k$ is less than or equal to the absolute value of $n$
> > > > > > then
> > > > > > $\sigma(k)$ not equal to $\mathtt{null}$
> > > > >
> > > > > if
> > > > >
> > > > > > $k$ strictly less than $-|n|$
> > > > > > or
> > > > > > $k$ strictly greater than $+|n|$
> > > > > > then
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) = \mathtt{null}$

Additionally, $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\sigma(-|k|) = \sigma(+|k|)}$

---

**Edit**

We should have written $\sigma(n-|k|) = \sigma(|k|)$ where $n$ is the minimum non-negative zalen integer from $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sigma(n-|k|) = \mathtt{null}$

---

---

**Germanische Darstellung der Definition von Unicode-Strings**

> Für jede Abbildung $\sigma$ aus den Zahlen ohne Null auf die Menge aller Unicode-Zeichen $\mathbb{U}$ sagen wir, dass $\sigma$ ein ***String*** ist
>
> > wenn und nur wenn
>
> Es $n$ Elementr der Zahlen ohne Null gibt, so dass:
>
> > wenn
> >
> > > der absolute Wert von $n$ kleiner oder gleich dem absoluten Wert von $m$ ist
> > > dann
> > > gilt für jedes $k$-Element der Menge aller Zahlen ohne Null,
> > >
> > > > alles Folgende:
> > > >
> > > > > wenn
> > > > >
> > > > > > $-|n|$ kleiner oder gleich $k$ ist
> > > > > > und
> > > > > > $k$ kleiner oder gleich dem absoluten Wert von $n$ ist
> > > > > > dann
> > > > > > ist $\sigma(k)$ ungleich $\mathtt{null}$
> > > > >
> > > > > wenn
> > > > >
> > > > > > $k$ streng kleiner als $-|n|$
> > > > > > oder
> > > > > > $k$ strikt größer als $+|n|$ ist
> > > > > > dann ist
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) = \mathtt{null}$

---

**Mostly Symbolic Representation of the Definition of Unicode String**

> $\forall \sigma \subseteq (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) \times (\mathbb{U}) \in $ the set of all finite-length ***strings***
>
> > $\iff$
>
> $\forall z, z^{\prime} \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \land \forall \mathtt{ch}, \mathtt{ch}^{\prime} \in \mathbb{U} (\sigma(z) = \sigma(z^{\prime})) \implies (\mathtt{ch} = \mathtt{ch}^{\prime})$
>
> $\land$
>
> $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \backepsilon$
>
> > > $|n| \leq |m|$
> > > $\implies$
> > > $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$,
> > >
> > > > all of the following:
> > > >
> > > > > > $-|n| \leq k \leq +|n|$
> > > > > > $\implies$
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) \neq \mathtt{null}$
> > > > >
> > > > > > $k < -|n|$ or $k > +|n|$
> > > > > > $\implies$
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) = \mathtt{null}$

---

**Notation for Strings**

In addition to the so-called *ASCII printables* shown above, do not forget the following:

| Name of Character | Interface | Implementation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tabs | $\mathtt{“\backslash t”}$ | $9$ |
| line-feeds | $\mathtt{“\backslash n”}$ | $10$ |
| carriage returns | $“\mathtt{\backslash r}”$ | $13$ |
| back-slash characters. | $“\mathtt{\backslash\backslash}”$ | $13$ |
| null | $\mathtt{null}$ | $92$ |

In order to avoid trouble distiguishing between the number zero and the leftmost letter $\mathtt{“O”}$ in $\mathtt{“Oxford”}$, we write $\mathtt{null} = \mathtt{0}$.

Quotation marks have meaning. Consider the following set:

> $$ A = \{ \mathtt{“\backslash t”}, \mathtt{“\backslash n”,} “\mathtt{\backslash r}”, “\mathtt{\backslash\backslash}”,  \mathtt{null},   “\mathtt{null}” \}  $$

- The string $“\mathtt{null}”$ using quotation marks is

  1. the letter $“\mathtt{n}”$
  2. the letter $“\mathtt{u}”$
  3. the letter $“\mathtt{l}”$
  4. the letter $“\mathtt{l}”$
- $\mathtt{null}$ without quotation marks is the number zero.

As an additional example, the following contains a tab-character, not a number 9

$(\mathtt{“normal”}, 9, \mathtt{“distribution”})$

---

## North American Definition of Subsequence

> For any two strings $\sigma$ and $\Sigma$, $\sigma$ is a ***sub-sequence*** of $\Sigma$ if and only if for every $z$ element of the zalen integers there exists  $K$ element of the zalen integers such that $k$ is less than or equal to $K$ and $\sigma(k)$ is $\Sigma(K)$

---

## Deutsche Definition einer Untersequenz

> Für zwei beliebige Zeichenketten $\sigma$ und $\Sigma$ ist $\sigma$ genau dann eine ***Untersequenz*** von $\Sigma$, wenn für jedes $z$-Element der Menge der Ganzzahlen ein $K$-Element der Menge der Ganzzahlen existiert, so dass $k$ kleiner oder gleich $K$ ist und $\sigma(k)$ $\Sigma(K)$ ist

---

## Mostly symbolic Definition of Subsequence

> For any two strings $\sigma$ and $\Sigma$, $\sigma$ is a ***sub-sequence*** of $\Sigma \iff \forall z \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \exists K \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}: k \leq K  \land \sigma(k) = \Sigma(K)$